# Remove photo only source with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I remove only the src not the whole image I tried something like this

```
$(this).parent().find('img').not(this).remove();
```

But it is not working it deletes the image and then when I try to upload again it does not upload because it can not find the image

Comment: Set the src attribute to an empty string.

Comment: What do you mean remove the src?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the src attribute, set it to null

```
$(this).parent().find('img').not(this).attr(src, null);
```

Or you can use the jquery `.removeAttr()` mehtod:

```
$(this).parent().find('img').not(this).removeAttr(src);
```

[More information here on .removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('img').not(this).attr("src","");
```